# how to do the same Nodejs crypto aes encryption CTR in PHP7?

Tags: php, html, node.js, encryption, aes

so here is the nodejs code that i took from internet.

```
// Nodejs encryption with CTR
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-128-ofb',
    password = 'password12';

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password)
  var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}

var hw = encrypt("hello world")
// outputs hello world
console.log(decrypt(hw));
```

its working fine

but when i try decrypt it with **openssl_decrypt** in php7 i got wrong/different result.

can someone help?

Comment: Can you add your php code for decryption?

Comment: There are some library for that . [This](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/4238-PHP-Encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-AES-in-pure-PHP.html) is one of them.

Comment: @Pete yes, im trying with openssl_decrypt OPENSSL_RAW_DATA it returning bump random symbolic..

Comment: @DavidJawHpan ok i will give a try

Comment: May the NodeJS code be modified? `crypto.createCipher` is deprecated and also uses a non-standard (and not very secure) KDF to derive the key and IV, that would have to be implemented in the PHP code (which wouldn't be very complex, though). So if it's possible to switch to `crypto.createCipheriv`, this should be done. This is more secure and also key and IV can be specified here directly (or derived via _reliable_ KDFs). Furthermore, porting to PHP is easier. Besides, title and posted code are contradictory with regard to the mode (CTR vs OFB). Which mode is actually meant?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the PHP code is not giving you the answer you expect is that crypto.createCipher uses another function to derive a key and initialization vector (iv) from the supplied password.

The function in question is [EVP_BytesToKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html).

Below is the PHP code that will decrypt your ciphertext. I've also included an encrypt function so you can encrypt in the same manner in PHP.

```
function EVP_BytesToKey($data, $count, $cipher, $hashMethod) {
    $iv_length  = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $key_length = $iv_length; // This assumption may not always be true...
    $result = "";
    $digestInput = "";
    while(strlen($result) < ($key_length + $iv_length)) {
        $digestInput .= $data;
        $digest = openssl_digest($digestInput, $hashMethod);
        for ($iteration = 1; $iteration < $count; $iteration++) {
            $digest = openssl_digest(hex2bin($digest), $hashMethod);
        }
        $digestInput = hex2bin($digest);
        $result .= hex2bin($digest);
    }
    return (object)["key" => substr($result, 0, $key_length), "iv" => substr($result, $key_length, $iv_length)];
}

function decrypt($encryptedHex, $cipher, $password) {
    $encrypted = hex2bin($encryptedHex);
    $evp = EVP_BytesToKey($password, 1, $cipher, "md5");
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $cipher, $evp->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $evp->iv);
}

function encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $password) {
    $evp = EVP_BytesToKey($password, 1, $cipher, "md5");
    return bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $evp->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $evp->iv));
}

$algorithm = "aes-128-ofb";
$password = "password12";
$encryptedHex = "f2211645785e4232339a0d";

echo "Ciphertext (hex): " . $encryptedHex . "\n";
echo "Plaintext: " . decrypt($encryptedHex, $algorithm, $password);
```